# Error in included django template is not rendered

Tags: django, templates, attributeerror

I have this simple template that uses the [imgix plugin](https://github.com/pancentric/django-imgix/) like so:

```
// template_b.html
{% get_imgix project.picture %}
```

This line causes an error and should be replaced by

```
{% get_imgix project.picture.url %}
```

This piece of code is inside a template that is included:

```
// template_a.html
{% include "template_b.html" %}
```

It seems that when the template tags fails, in the first case (an `AttributeError` is raised), the template is *simply* ignored. No error is raised if the `DEBUG` setting is `False`.

While this is certainly useful to prevent any user-facing errors, it's still concerning to not have any kind of feedback.

Do you know where I can find more information related to this behavior and if there are ways to still be informed of the failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not the only person to have been caught out from this behaviour. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/hscW1VboJxY/KpgDWvClHQAJ) on the django-developers mailing list.

The silencing behaviour [has been deprecated in Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#id2). In Django 2.1 the exception will be raised. In Django 1.11 and 2.0 you get a deprecation warning if the include tag raises and exception, but the exception is silenced.

I don't have any good suggestions for earlier versions of Django. You could create your own `include` tag if it's really important to you.