# Django test client ignores "include" terms in Django template

Tags: django, testing, django-testing

I have an issue with Django tests client.
Let for the `home` path I have this template (`home.html`):

```
<html>
    <body>
       {% include 'example.html' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and in `example.html` I have error:

```
<div>
   {% non_registered_tag arg1 arg2 %}
</div>
```

I wrote a test for accessibility to a Django URL.

```
class HomePageAccess(TestCase):
  def test_home_page(self):
    client = Client()
    response = client.get(reverse_lazy('home'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

This code fails successfully if there be an error in `home.html`, But if there be an error in `example.html` which is included in `home.html` Test will pass even though we expect to fail because I included it in `home.html` and in the browser I encounter an error (status code 500) while this not happens in test client.

Is it normal? I'm using Django 2.0.2.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In your `settings.py` do you have the `debug` option set in the `OPTIONS` dictionary of the `TEMPLATES` setting? And also what is the value of the overall `DEBUG` setting in `settings.py`?

Comment: May be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758492/error-in-included-django-template-is-not-rendered Exceptions are silenced in `include` tags when `DEBUG` is False.

Comment: @WillKeeling You right! in the template `OPTIONS` dictionary `debug` was not set to true. I changed And it working now. thanks.

Comment: @WillKeeling It will be appreciated if you add your answer. So I can accept and vote-up. thanks.

Comment: answer added - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what's happening here is that you have the `debug` option set to `False`  in the `OPTIONS` section in the `TEMPLATES` setting, or you have omitted it entirely (in which case it assumes the value of the overall `DEBUG` setting).

Explicitly setting `debug` to `True` should expose the error and your test should fail as expected.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': True,
        },
    },
]
```

More information on the `debug` setting can be found in the template section of the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates).